# MySQL query php variable in variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP function that makes a query to MySQL DB.

```
function regEvent($event, $l)
{
$sqlz_upd="UPDATE {$event} SET f1a='$_POST[F1A"'.$l.'"]'";
```

The question is what is the syntax to use variable $l in $_POST[F1A$l]?

Comment: Side note: Read up on [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["F1A".$l]);
$sqlz_upd="UPDATE {$event} SET f1a='$var' ";
```

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but note that answering with code with injection vulnerabilitles is regarded downvote-worthy by many! (myself included usually.)

Answer (score 4):

```
$condition = $_POST["F1A" . $l];
$sqlz_upd="UPDATE {$event} SET f1a='".mysql_real_escape_string($condition)."'";
```

This is how to use your dynamic post and be safe for Sql Injection.

Comment: This wil definitly do the tric!

Comment: Even better would be to look into PHPs PDO.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a string as key in an associative array. It should be enclosed in single or double quotes(though PHP won't give any error).

i.e.   `$_POST['F1A'. $l]  or $_POST["F1A$l"]`

my suggestion will be...

```
$sqlz_upd="UPDATE {$event} SET f1a='" . $_POST["F1A$l"] . "'";
```